# How to manually make a dynamic body(ball) to pass into the box in box2d iPhone

Tags: iphone, box2d-iphone

As I am newbie to the cocos2d and I am struggling alot.Can anyone suggest me how to work on this.

1. I am having 3 boxes(which are kinematic bodies)
2. Also having multiple balls(which are dynamic bodies) which is having a tag value(box number) for each ball.
3. I am having some obstacles(kinematic bodies) in between from where the ball is shooten and the boxes.

The scenario is I will get box number randomly ex: 2(second box) and is set as tha tag value to the ball. And the ball should pass into the second box exactly even it hits the obstacles.And if I got the box number for the next ball as 3 the ball should pass into the third box.

Can anyone please suggest me,

Thank you,
Monish

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple helper class to create balls and return. You could use similar approach to make boxes.

```
//
//  Ball.h
//  BouncingBall
//
//  Created by Omar Hussain on 8/12/10.
//  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box2D.h"

class Ball : public CCSprite {
public:
    CCSprite *sprite;
    b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
    b2Body *ballBody;
    b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
    b2Fixture *fixture;
    Ball(b2World *world);
    b2Vec2 disp;
    CCSprite *shadowBall;
    b2World *world;
    bool isAnimating;
    void SetBallOverlap(bool willOverlap, int scale);
    void Destroy();
};


#import "Ball.h"

#define Density 1.0f
#define Friction 1.0f
#define Restitution 0.8f
#define PTM_RATIO 32
#define SpriteRadius 40.5


Ball::Ball(b2World *world){
    this->world = world;
    this->sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"5.png"];
    [sprite setPosition:ccp(160,460)];  
    this->isAnimating = false;
    //Set up sprite
    ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    ballBodyDef.position.Set(160/PTM_RATIO, 460/PTM_RATIO);
    ballBodyDef.userData = sprite;
    this->ballBody = world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);

    b2CircleShape circle;
    circle.m_radius = SpriteRadius/PTM_RATIO;

    ballShapeDef.shape = &circle;
    ballShapeDef.density = Density;
    ballShapeDef.friction =Friction;
    ballShapeDef.restitution = Restitution;
    this->fixture = this->ballBody->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef);

    //this->shadowBall = [TSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball_shadow.png"];


}
void Ball::SetBallSize(int scale){
    this->ballBody->DestroyFixture(fixture);
    this->world->DestroyBody(ballBody);

    ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    ballBodyDef.position.Set(160/PTM_RATIO, 460/PTM_RATIO);
    ballBodyDef.userData = sprite;
    this->ballBody = world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);
    float  correctedScale = scale/9.0;
    b2CircleShape circle;
    circle.m_radius = (correctedScale *SpriteRadius)/PTM_RATIO;

    ballShapeDef.shape = &circle;
    ballShapeDef.density = Density;
    ballShapeDef.friction = Friction;
    ballShapeDef.restitution = Restitution;
    this->fixture = this->ballBody->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef);
    //this->shadowBall.scale = scale;
    this->sprite.scale = correctedScale;
}
void Ball::SetBallOverlap(bool willOverlap, int scale){
    this->world->DestroyBody(ballBody);

    ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    ballBodyDef.position.Set(160/PTM_RATIO, 460/PTM_RATIO);
    ballBodyDef.userData = sprite;
    this->ballBody = world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);
    float  correctedScale = scale/9.0;
    b2CircleShape circle;
    circle.m_radius = (correctedScale *SpriteRadius)/PTM_RATIO;

    ballShapeDef.shape = &circle;
    ballShapeDef.density = Density;
    ballShapeDef.friction = Friction;
    ballShapeDef.restitution = Restitution;
    if(willOverlap)
        ballShapeDef.filter.groupIndex = 1;
    else 
        ballShapeDef.filter.groupIndex = -1;
    this->ballBody->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef);
}
void Ball::Destroy(){
    this->ballBody->DestroyFixture(fixture);
    this->world->DestroyBody(ballBody);
}
```